# Manually sketch graph and import into NetworkX

Tags: python, graph, graphics, drawing, networkx

I'd like to manually sketch out a graph topology (literally point and click), and then use that sketch to create a `Graph` object using Python's `NetworkX` library, preferably (though not absolutely necessary) in a Windows environment.

It would probably work to draw the graph in Inkscape, and then parse the `xml` file to create a `NetworkX` `Graph`; this seems clunky, though. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I maintain an interactive graph plotting library that has some support for doing this. It's called `netgraph` and you can find it on [github](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) or install it via pip. The project started out as a fork of the networkx drawing facilities (which were insufficient for my needs), so the API is pretty similar.

[image]

### MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx

from netgraph import InteractivelyConstructDestroyGraph

# initialise figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# set size of axis to draw on
ax.set(xlim=[-2, 2], ylim=[-2, 2])

# initialise graph;
# netgraph supports many graph input formats but an empty graph is not one of them;
# hence we pass in a single edge in an edge list format
g = InteractivelyConstructDestroyGraph([(0, 1)], draw_arrows=True, ax=ax)
plt.show()

# manipulate graph:
#   Pressing 'A' will add a node to the graph.
#   Pressing 'D' will remove a selected node.
#   Pressing 'a' will add edges between all selected nodes.
#   Pressing 'd' will remove edges between all selected nodes.
#   Pressing 'r' will reverse the direction of edges between all selected nodes.
#   Nodes can be selected and moved using the mouse.

# get current edge list
edge_list = g.edge_list

# get current node positions, which is a dict int node : (float x, float y) (same format as in networkx)
node_positions = g.node_positions

# create graph in networkx
G = networkx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)

# reproduce plot in networkx
networkx.draw(G, pos=node_positions)
plt.show()
```

### Note

This part of the code base is still fairly ... experimental (I literally just merged and uploaded the relevant bits when I saw your question). Any bug reports are hence especially welcome. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [NetworkX's docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html), there's mention of "Cytoscape, Gephi, Graphviz and, for LaTeX typesetting, PGF/TikZ".

I'm currently trying [Gephi](https://gephi.org), which seems to be very close to what I want, although a bit laggy.